Differential representation of equation
I'm looking for some help getting the differential form in (6) from (5). The procedure up to this point has been to express changes in one variable as the sum of functions of changes in the independent variables e.g. $d(uv) = udv + vdu$ then divide by some of the independent variables. However, on this equation, I'm at a loss. How can I get from (5) to (6)?

Here is what I have so far:
$T = t+t\frac{k-1}{2}M^2$
$\rightarrow dT = \left[dt + dt\frac{k-1}{2}M^2\right] + \left[t+t\frac{k-1}{2}(dM)^2 \right]$
$\rightarrow dT = dt\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}M^2\right)+t\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}(dM)^2\right)$
but $\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}M^2\right) = \frac{T}{t}$ so
$\rightarrow dT = dt\frac{T}{t} + t\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}(dM)^2\right)$
$\rightarrow \frac{dT}{T} = \frac{dt}{t} + \frac{t}{T}\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}(dM)^2\right)$
but $\left(1+\frac{k-1}{2}M^2\right)^{-1} = \frac{t}{T}$
so $\rightarrow \frac{dT}{T} = \frac{dt}{t} + \frac{1+\frac{k-1}{2}(dM)^2}{1+\frac{k-1}{2}M^2}$
Now what?

$dF(x, y) = F(dx, y) + F(x, dy)$ is nonsense. Ditto: your first equation for $dT,.$ This should be $$dT = \left[dt + dt\frac{k-1}{2}M^2\right] + \left[t+t\frac{k-1}{2}\right],\color{red}{d(M^2)},.$$ (What you derive then is clearly nonsense as well.)

@KurtG. Sorry, that was me very poorly (and admittedly incorrectly) expressing the product rule (where $u=t$ and $v=1+\frac{k-1}{2}M^2$)

Equation (6) can obviously be simplified to
$$\tag6
\frac{dT}T=\frac{dt}t+\frac{(k-1)/2}{1+(k-1)/2M^2}\,d(M^2)\,.
$$
From (5),
\begin{align}
\frac{dT}T=d(\log T)=d(\log t)+d\Big(\log\big(1+\tfrac{k-1}{2} M^2\big)\Big)\,.
\end{align}
Can you finish?

Ohhh lots of chain rule applications right?

@SterlingButters it does not matter how we call the rules. Can you finish?

Yes I can, thanks!
